# Procedure to apply formatting to all rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I had a SQL procedure that increments through each row and and pads some trailing zeros on values depending on the length of the value after a decimal point. Trying to carry this over to a PSQL environment I realized there was a lot of syntax differences between SQL and PSQL. I managed to make the conversion over time but I am still getting a syntax error and cant figure out why. Can someone help me figure out why this wont run? I am currently running it in PGadmin if that makes any difference.

```
DO $$

DECLARE 
counter integer;
before decimal;  
after decimal;

BEGIN
counter := 1;
WHILE counter <> 2 LOOP 


    before = (select code from table where ID = counter);  

    after = (SELECT SUBSTRING(code, CHARINDEX('.', code) + 1, LEN(code)) as Afterward from table where ID = counter);   

    IF before = after  
    THEN
    update table set code = before + '.0000' where ID = counter;  

    ELSE
        IF length(after) = 1 THEN
        update table set code = before + '000' where ID = counter;
        ELSE IF length(after) = 2 THEN
        update table set code = before + '00' where ID = counter;
        ELSE IF length(after) = 3 THEN
        update table set code = before + '0' where ID = counter;
        ELSE
        select before;
        END IF;
    END IF;

counter := counter + 1;

END LOOP
END $$;
```

Some examples of the input/output of the intended result:

```
Input 55.5 >  Output  55.5000
Input 55   >  Output 55.0000
```

Thanks for your help,
Justin

Comment: A side note: "SQL" is a query language which is used by PostgreSQL "psql" is the command line client for Postgres. The language you are using for the function is called PL/pgSQL - which is a procedural extension to SQL.

Comment: The most obvious error: SQL uses `||` to concatenate strings, not `+`. Postgres also has no `charindex()` function. Can you [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output? It seems this doesn't require any procedural language at all.

Comment: And why are you storing numbers in text columns?

Comment: Hi Horse, Thanks for the responses. I am new to PL/pgSQL as of today so forgive any terrible decisions haha. I am more versed in SQL. As for the text question, it isnt necessary to be text variables, I could and should probably use a decimal type. Edits above

Comment: Postgres does use SQL (as every other relational DBMS) so you should feel at home.

Comment: As for the charindex, i am not sure what pgSQL uses to find a character within a string? Or subsequently how I can use that found character to create a substring from the right side of it.

Comment: The functions are all documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in a database query?  Usually this sort of formatting is done when rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a function or even an update on the table to format values when *displaying* them.

Assuming the values are in fact numbers stored in a `decimal` or `float` column, all you need to do is to apply the `to_char()` function when retrieving them:

```
select to_char(code, 'FM999999990.0000')
from data;
```

This will output 55.5000 or 55.0000

The drawback of the `to_char()` function is that you need to anticipate the maximum number of digits of that can occur. If you have not enough `9` in the format mask, the output will be something like `#.###`. But as too many digits in the format mask don't hurt, I usually throw a lot into the format mask.

For more information on formatting functions, please see the manual: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE

---

If you insist on storing formatted data, you can use `to_char()` to update the table:

```
update the_table
  set code = to_char(code::numeric, 'FM999999990.0000');
```

Casting the value to a number will of course fail if there a non-numeric values in the column.

But again: I strong recommend to store numbers as numbers, not as strings.

If you want to compare this to a user input, it's better to convert the user input to a proper number and compare *that* to the (number) values stored in the database.

---

The string matching that you are after doesn't actually require a function either. Using `substring()` with a regex will do that:

```
update the_table 
   set code = code || case length(coalesce(substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$'), ''))
         when 4 then '0'
         when 3 then '00'
         when 2 then '000'
         when 1 then '0000'
         when 0 then '.0000'
         else ''
       end
 where length(coalesce(substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$'), '')) < 5;
```

`substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$')` extracts everything the `.` followed by numbers that is at the end of the string. So for `55.0` it returns `.0` for `55.50` it returns `.50` if there is no `.` in the value, then it returns `null` that's why the coalesce is needed.

The length of that substring tells us how many digits are present. Depending on that we can then append the necessary number of zeros. The `case` can be shortened so that not all possible length have to be listed (but it's not simpler):

```
update the_table
    set code = code || case length(coalesce(substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$'), ''))
         when 0 then '.0000'
         else lpad('0', 5- length(coalesce(substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$'), '')), '0')
       end
 where length(coalesce(substring(code from '\.[0-9]*$'), '')) < 5;
```

Another option is to use the position of the `.` inside the string to calculate the number of `0` that need to be added:

```
update the_table
     set code = 
       code || case 
         when strpos(code, '.') = 0 then '0000'
         else rpad('0', 4 - (length(code) - strpos(code, '.')), '0')
       end
where length(code) - strpos(code, '.') < 4;
```

Regular expressions are quite expensive not using them will make this faster. The above will however only work if there is always at most one `.` in the value.

But if you can be sure that every value *can* be cast to a number, the `to_char()` method with a cast is definitely the most robust one.

---

To only process rows where the `code` columns contains correct numbers, you can use a where clause in the SQL statement:

```
where code ~ '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$'
```

Comment: I do not need to display anything in particular actually. I am attempting to pad values like the example i gave above for every row in a database, about 20k rows. Only reason i have the select in the else statement is because i didnt know what else to put in there. May not even need anything, i wasnt sure if it would throw an error if it was empty.

Comment: @Justin: you shouldn't be storing numbers as `varchar`. Never. And if you store them in columns with the correct data type (e.g. `decimal`) there is no need to "format" them, because numbers (just like dates) are stored without any format. You apply the format when retrieving them, not when storing them.

Comment: I am not attempting to format any fields. This is simply a database for a software that is already built, I have no control over how it was made and in the inner workings of it. I believe the people the wrote it are using these decimals in ways only strings can be used. I am just working with what iv got. I agree with all of you though.

Comment: Anyway, I understand I can apply format when retrieving them. But in the case i am using them I am not retrieving them but rather comparing a value a user imports on the software to the value in the database. We are trying to normalize the whole thing. If the user enters  55.50  but in the Database its 55.5 they wont match. So instead the whole database will be Padded to 4 digits i.e.  55.5000. And on the software side, when the user enters 55.50, it will also be padded to 55.5000 (this side of things is already done).

Comment: So i just need all the database values to be padded to 4 digits. This is easily done in SQL for me, but as you can tell i am having trouble in pgSQL

Comment: @Justin you can use the same expression in an update statement: `update data set code = to_char(code, 'FM999999990.0000');`

Comment: @Justin: my answer **is** using SQL, no PL/pgSQL involved.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You could also add a where clause to avoid idempotent updates:  `UPDATE data SET code = to_char(code, 'FM999999990.0000') WHERE code <> to_char(code, 'FM999999990.0000');`

Comment: I looked deeper into the fields last night and found that some of the values of the many thousands do actually have characters A-Z in there. Which is why it was stored as Varchar/text  rather than a decimal. I will try out some of the suggestions you all left, hopefully something will solve my issue. Thank you all for your responses

Comment: @Justin you can make the statement only process valid numbers by using using a regex in the where clause: e.g. `where code ~ '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$'`

Comment: Horse you are awesome, and thank you to every one else who responded too. This worked like a charm for me and it was much simpler than I thought. I was definitely over thinking the solution to this. Thanks again

Comment: So turns out even though this works perfectly for updating the fields, there seems to be a truncation error when attempting to run it for multiple rows. I was able to make it up to 2000 rows so far but then i start getting this error: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(10)
SQL state: 22001

Comment: @Justin: then apparently there was a value like `123456789.0` which - when you pad it with 4 zeros at the end, it will exceed the 10 characters. You need to increase the size of that column or maybe indeed change everything to be proper number....

Comment: Now its only allowing me to run it 1 row at a time. Which would be fine if i didnt have like 80k rows left to go haha. Any idea why this would be happening for an update? The select seems to work fine. I have tried updating 500 rows at a time down to 2 at a time. Same error.

Comment: Ah i see thank you, i didnt think about the column size. Ill leave you alone now Horse with my silly questions haha

Answer (score 0):

To change the column type to numeric:

```
alter table t alter column code type numeric
```